# MVC with Observer Pattern

Tags: java, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

I'm working with the `MVC` pattern, which also uses the `Observer` pattern. The concept is like the following:

```
________                 _________                ______________
| VIEW | -- observes --> | MODEL | <-- changes -- | CONTROLLER | 
--------                 ---------                --------------
```

So I think my concept is pretty usual and common. Each time an observed object from the `Model` is changed, the `View` updates with a recreation. In my case, i have a lot of objects changing very frequently, which has a bad influence on the performance of the user interface. Because of a wide range of possible changes of the objects and the way of presenting them, i always have to newly create the whole `View` on update instead of updating particular components. To improve the performance I implemented a queue for update view request to make sure, updates are only done e.g. max. every 50 milliseconds. This works perfectly and increased the performance to a good level.

My question is now, is there a better way to deal with many update view requests, that temporally overlap each other. My solution to queue and reduce the request to an acceptable level seems to me like a bad workaround. Any ideas for a better concept?

Comment: Could you add some more information about how your view looks like? As far as I understand you create again a new view each time you change something in the model. Could the changes in the model be agrouped? Could your view be changed by using setters instead of create another one? In this particular case, does view mean graphic view?

Comment: Yes i'm talking about a grphic view. But what is viewed is not relevant for the question, i want to discus the concept. Partly updates of the view are not possible or too costy because an object and the view representation are not mapped 1 to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you are picturing in you diagram is not exactly MVC, but rather MVVM (Model, View, ViewModel).
Using a queue to throttle the changes is a perfectly valid approach. In many case, it is useless to try to update a view faster than what the user is able to perceive.

On the other hand, rather than creating new View objects each time might be expensive. Another trick you could apply is to have a pool of mutable view parts, based on demand, you re-bind them to some of your model entities and display or hide them on demand. Depending on your specific use case, this could also help you to improve global performances.

Comment: Ok, then i won't have a bad conscience for using this approach :) Thanks for explaining. But I think i'm still using a simple MVC because when the Model changes the View just stupidly rebuilds itself notified by the Obeserver (Model is the Obeservable). So there is no data binding or binding layer between View and Model

Comment: @alex Yes. Precisely what I thought. Isn' the responsibility of binding the  model and view together lies with Controller. To make myself clear Controller should be the place where View attaches itself to a Model. I am just conceptualizing as I don't have the running code but I want to convert my Java web application to Desktop one and want to know if my assumption is correct?

Comment: I think different approaches are possible depending on your requirements. [View] <--- notify to update from model -- [Controller] would also be a possible approach. Then the view just works with the controller and notifies the view when it should update. In that case you would have something like a dumb model that just stores data